# Error while performing aggregation query in elastic search . "illegal_argument_exception / Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I am performing a curl request to an elastic search instance. However i am getting an error as below.

```
curl -X GET "localhost:57457/mep-reports*/_search?pretty&size=0" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary @query.txt

 Response.

    {
      "error" : {
        "root_cause" : [
          {
            "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [status] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
          }
        ],
        "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason" : "all shards failed",
        "phase" : "query",
        "grouped" : true,
        "failed_shards" : [
          {
            "shard" : 0,
            "index" : "mep-reports",
            "node" : "NJuAFq3YSni4TIK9PzgJxg",
            "reason" : {
              "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
              "reason" : "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [status] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
            }
          }
        ],
        "caused_by" : {
          "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason" : "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [status] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.",
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [status] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
          }
        }
      },
      "status" : 400
    }
```

any idea how to fix it . the following is my mapping definition i got

```
curl-XGET"localhost:57457/mep-reports*/_mapping/field/*?pretty"


{
   "mep-reports":{
      "mappings":{
         "doc":{
            "_index":{
               "full_name":"_index",
               "mapping":{

               }
            },
            "status.keyword":{
               "full_name":"status.keyword",
               "mapping":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "inventory":{
               "full_name":"inventory",
               "mapping":{
                  "inventory":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "flight_name.keyword":{
               "full_name":"flight_name.keyword",
               "mapping":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "nof_segments":{
               "full_name":"nof_segments",
               "mapping":{
                  "nof_segments":{
                     "type":"long"
                  }
               }
            },
            "_all":{
               "full_name":"_all",
               "mapping":{

               }
            },
            "_ignored":{
               "full_name":"_ignored",
               "mapping":{

               }
            },
            "campaign_name":{
               "full_name":"campaign_name",
               "mapping":{
                  "campaign_name":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "_parent":{
               "full_name":"_parent",
               "mapping":{

               }
            },
            "flight_id.keyword":{
               "full_name":"flight_id.keyword",
               "mapping":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "flight_name":{
               "full_name":"flight_name",
               "mapping":{
                  "flight_name":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "@version":{
               "full_name":"@version",
               "mapping":{
                  "@version":{
                     "type":"long"
                  }
               }
            },
            "_version":{
               "full_name":"_version",
               "mapping":{

               }
            },
            "campaign_id":{
               "full_name":"campaign_id",
               "mapping":{
                  "campaign_id":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "_routing":{
               "full_name":"_routing",
               "mapping":{

               }
            },
            "_type":{
               "full_name":"_type",
               "mapping":{

               }
            },
            "msg_text":{
               "full_name":"msg_text",
               "mapping":{
                  "msg_text":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "delivery_ts":{
               "full_name":"delivery_ts",
               "mapping":{
                  "delivery_ts":{
                     "type":"long"
                  }
               }
            },
            "sender.keyword":{
               "full_name":"sender.keyword",
               "mapping":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "submission_ts":{
               "full_name":"submission_ts",
               "mapping":{
                  "submission_ts":{
                     "type":"long"
                  }
               }
            },
            "flight_id":{
               "full_name":"flight_id",
               "mapping":{
                  "flight_id":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "_seq_no":{
               "full_name":"_seq_no",
               "mapping":{

               }
            },
            "@timestamp":{
               "full_name":"@timestamp",
               "mapping":{
                  "@timestamp":{
                     "type":"date"
                  }
               }
            },
            "account_id":{
               "full_name":"account_id",
               "mapping":{
                  "account_id":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "_field_names":{
               "full_name":"_field_names",
               "mapping":{

               }
            },
            "sender":{
               "full_name":"sender",
               "mapping":{
                  "sender":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "recipient":{
               "full_name":"recipient",
               "mapping":{
                  "recipient":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "account_id.keyword":{
               "full_name":"account_id.keyword",
               "mapping":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "_source":{
               "full_name":"_source",
               "mapping":{

               }
            },
            "_id":{
               "full_name":"_id",
               "mapping":{

               }
            },
            "campaign_name.keyword":{
               "full_name":"campaign_name.keyword",
               "mapping":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "_uid":{
               "full_name":"_uid",
               "mapping":{

               }
            },
            "recipient.keyword":{
               "full_name":"recipient.keyword",
               "mapping":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "inventory.keyword":{
               "full_name":"inventory.keyword",
               "mapping":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "msg_text.keyword":{
               "full_name":"msg_text.keyword",
               "mapping":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "status":{
               "full_name":"status",
               "mapping":{
                  "status":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "campaign_id.keyword":{
               "full_name":"campaign_id.keyword",
               "mapping":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

really appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, it appear that you are trying to perform aggregation on a `text` field i.e. `status`.

Note that you cannot perform `aggregation` on a `text` field and that in order to do so, you need to have `fielddata:true`. 
However this is not recommended as it would consume lot of heap space which is what you see in the error.

The mapping you've shared has the below details for `status` field.

```
{
   "status":{
      "type":"text",
      "fields":{
         "keyword":{
            "type":"keyword",
            "ignore_above":256
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I see that `status` has a sibling field in `status.keyword`.

Just change your query that you would have in your `query.txt` to make use of `status.keyword` instead of `status` in your aggregation query and it should fix the issue.

Likewise if you see more errors like that, you may want to make similar changes on the other fields too accordingly. Note that this change is something you need to do in your `aggregation` query.

Let me know if this helps!